ThermostatController has a max temperature when setting up a routine in Alexa app
I've developed an Alexa Skill.
When I'm going to set up a routine for a faucet device, the input stepper that appears to choose the temperature doesn't increase pass 32º Celsius. This stepper is part of the ThermostatController interface.
Here is the json of the response from my skill, I don't know if I lack any param.
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "3f178189-ac15-41a5-af4d-6d0da551491b"
        },
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "endpointId": "17202003@1d417d4b092a922a95761ed5909d2b65d866a3e4",
                    "manufacturerName": "Mnix",
                    "friendlyName": "Faucet - 17202003",
                    "description": "17202003",
                    "displayCategories": [
                        "OTHER"
                    ],
                    "cookie": {},
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa",
                            "version": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "powerState"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": false,
                                "retrievable": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.ThermostatController",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "targetSetpoint"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": false,
                                "retrievable": false
                            },
                            "configuration": {
                                "lockoutTemperature": {
                                    "heating": {
                                        "maximum": {
                                            "value": 61,
                                            "scale": "CELSIUS"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I expected the stepper to don't have a max limit.
